# What causes an excel file to open as read-only?

Tags: excel, vba

An excel file exists on a network that can be accessed by several users.

However, after some investigation it was found that some users open the file as read-only.

I'm opening the file with VBA and workBook.Open(). This routine has a read-only property, but even explicitly sending this parameter as false, the file still opens as read only. When users who experienced this bug were asked to open the file straight from the network, the file opens as read only, despite being fine for other users. Additionally, permission rights to the folder has been ruled out as the cause.

Does macro security prevent a file from being opened normally? What else can cause a file to open as read-only?

More Details:
Windows 7
Excel 2007
.xls File Type

Comment: I'll get the obvious question out of the way.  Does anyone else have the file open? If the Excel file is already open, the next user will open it as Read-Only.

Comment: @PowerUser That's the baffling aspect of it. We know the users reporting these bugs have access rights to the folder (they can create/delete simple text files). We have tried with copied excel files (in the same dir) to ensure that additional users are not accessing the file, but to no avail. Additionally, the process of opening and saving the workbook via VBA works for several other end users.

Comment: How about permissions on the specific file itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Save As options/Tools/general Options ,there is a read-only recommended option, it can be.

[]'s